# Trouble understanding eager loading

Tags: entries, assets, eager-loading

I've tried to apply eager loading per Craft's docs, but it doesn't seem to work. When I do this, will I have access to all the entry fields? If not, do I have to include all the fields I want in the with attribute?

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').with['image'] %}
  {% set image = entry.image[0] ?? null %}
  {% if image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}">
  {% endif %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I tried it, the code barfed when trying to output {{ entry.title }}.

Comment: Would probably be helpful to replace the word `barfed` with the actual error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no `.with()` method for the ElementCriteriaModel nor is it supported by `craft.entries` as a chainable method, meaning that it can't be chained to `craft.entries` query like that:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').with['image'] %}
```

Especially as an array (hint: you were probably intending to use `.with(['image'])` instead of `.with['image']`.

The correct syntax for eager loading elements is:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    with: ['image']
}) %}
```

or in your case it can be:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries({ section: 'news', with:['image'] }) %}
  {% set image = entry.image[0] ?? null %}
  {% if image %}
    <img src="{{ image.url }}">
  {% endif %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

I remember also being frustrated by eager loading in craft (for some reason I also had problems using it at first), but then it turned to be quite useful. It's especially powerful if you'd like to show more then one image per entry, e.g.:

```
{% for i in entry.image %}
    <img src="{{ i.url }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

Take care

Comment: This answer is mostly correct, but I confirmed with @bradbell that `.with` should indeed work as a chained method.  

The syntax is `.with(['image']` or if wanting to eager load multiple things, then `.with(['image1','image2'])`

Comment: @JeremyDaalder oh nice, couldn't spot that in the official docs though…

Comment: That's why I checked with Brad ;) - might be worth editing that bit off the top above.

Answer (score 2):

The original answer is good, but as noted, somewhat incorrect, at least concerning a chainable `.with()` method.

Here's my attempt to explain things: [Speed up your Craft CMS Templates with Eager Loading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/speed-up-your-craft-cms-templates-with-eager-loading)